# What is the `args` section in an ansible command

Tags: ansible

This example only runs when /path/to/database doesn't exist:

```
# You can also use the 'args' form to provide the options.
- name: This command will change the working directory to somedir/ and will only run when /path/to/database doesn't exist.
  command: /usr/bin/make_database.sh arg1 arg2
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
    creates: /path/to/database
```

but why is it listed under `args:`?

And what's the `args:` setting for?

Answer (score 15):

`args` is used to explicitly pass named parameters to actions that support "free form" parameter – additional word `args` is required because in YAML (language used for Ansible playbooks) you can't assign string value for "root" key of a dictionary.

```
# here `command` is a string
command: /bin/echo ok

# here `user` is a dict
user:
  name: john
```

And because `command` is a string, you use `args` to pass additional parameters (like `chdir`, `creates`, etc). Whereas `user` is a dict, so you can add parameters straight in there (like `name`, `uid`, etc).